# Trouble with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to save videos from multiple cameras connected to a Raspberry Pi using OpenCV. I have the Video saving working when there is a single camera without any multiprocessing. But when I try to have each camera on its own process nothing happens. I do not get any errors or log messages or anything, the process does not start.

Here is, what I think, the relevant code.

```
def init():
    log(LOG_CODE_APP_START)
    # video_capture(0) <-- works perfectly!

    for index in range(0, 9):
        camera_check = cv.VideoCapture(index)
        if camera_check is None or not camera_check.isOpened():
            continue
        else:
            camera_index.append(index)

    print(camera_index) # <-- prints [0,1]
    processes = []
    for camera in camera_index:
        video_process = multiprocessing.Process(name=str(camera), target=video_capture, kwargs={'camera': camera})
        processes.append(video_process)

    for process in processes:
        print("Starting processes")
        process.start()

def video_capture(camera=None):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        capture = cv.VideoCapture(camera)
        capture.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
        capture.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
        log(LOG_CODE_NEW_VIDEO)
        file_name = 'camera_' + str(camera + 1) + '_' + '_' + get_time_string() + '_' + '.avi'
        fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        height, width = get_video_stream_height_width(capture)
        out = cv.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))
        while int(time.time() - start_time) < CAPTURE_TIME:
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            if ret:
                out.write(frame)

        capture.release()
        out.release()
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(VIDEO_STORE):
                os.mkdir(VIDEO_STORE)
            shutil.move(file_name, VIDEO_STORE + '/' + file_name)
            log(LOG_CODE_VIDEO_SAVED)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception")
            log_error(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script without multiprocessing to accept a camera number as a command-line argument.

Then try launching multiple instances of that script.

Comment: The number of cameras are variable and can't be known in advance. Hence the need for implementing it thus way.

Comment: Fair enough. But this way you can at least test of reading more then one camera at a time actually works. I can imagine that with multiple camera's connected to a single USB bus you might run into capacity problems at some point.

Comment: I have checked that I can have 2 cameras working at the same time.